# How to block some Jobs for some user level in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I want  a  block some jobs  for a user level for example I have 3 jobs:

Job1 (All the register user can execute this).
Job2 (Only some user can execute this)
Job3 (All the register user can execute this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Global Security (`http://<your_server>/configureSecurity/?`) to the configuration that matches most jobs (enable `Job Build`) and then enable `Project-based security` for the other jobs (via the jon configuration) and set up as required by disabling  `Job Build`.

Enter the user name in `User/group to add:` and then configure as required.  In this case I've limited control to two users

[image]

Comment: @DavidDominguez enable Job Build in Global Security  and then disable it for the project

Comment: Role-Based Strategy  official documentation (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) does not help me in anything. This is real example of a great documentation: http://www.kblearningacademy.com/configure-role-strategy-plugin-in-jenkins/

Comment: This doesn't work in 1.658 from the docs… <quote>ACLs are additive, so the access rights granted below will be effective for all the projects.</quote>

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy` to achieve this. Hudson/Jenkin >> Manage Hudson >> Configre Security >> Authorization, and select Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy. Now in the configuration page of each job you will have an option `Enable job-based security`. You can give access permissions for the users here.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me : Role Strategy Plugin

But you need understand it and its official documentation is poor, so go to :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38516162/3957754

Answer (score 0):

The below link provides the clear guideline to grant/restrict the access to Jenkins Jobs.
http://www.kblearningacademy.com/configure-role-strategy-plugin-in-jenkins/
Its very useful & am able to do the same.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.