# Jenkins: Hide job from anonymous users

Tags: jenkins, permissions, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins server that builds all of my public projects, but also some of my private ones. I'd like to allow all users (even anonymous) to view and download all of my public projects but i don't want them to be able to access my private ones.

I'm using matrix-based security and I gave anonymous global view and  discover permissions but I can't find a way to revoke those permissions for private projects.

Is there a way to do this (maybe a plugin) or will I have to revoke all permissions globally and grant them on each public project manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins restrict view of jobs per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323129/jenkins-restrict-view-of-jobs-per-user)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify job names patterns under Manage Jenkins →  Manage and Assign Roles → Manage Roles. See also [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin).

Comment: I tried the plugin but I can't make it work. I made a new role and assigned it to anonymous. I gave the role global read access but on the project specific part, I didn't give it any permissions. I think it's doing the same thing as the normal project-specific matrix: If a user has a global permission to do something, it ignores the lack of that permission on the project.