# Jenkins Permission's to user according to jobs

Tags: jenkins, authorization, jobs

Jenkins have permission's by Project-based Matrix and by Role strategy for read/write/admin.How to give access/permission to view  individual jobs/projects for different users ? Is there an existing plugin? 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is inbuilt. On a job, select "Enable project-based security" and specify permissions per user for this job only.

Comment: But this will work only with "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy". Bit outdated but still useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9925333/1586762