# jenkins restrict view of jobs with Categorized jobs per user

Tags: jenkins

[image: view job]
On Jenkins, I created an abc account. I want to sign in with the abc account, only can display the Client permission as shown in the picture and not display the Admin permission.

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins restrict view of jobs per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323129/jenkins-restrict-view-of-jobs-per-user)

Comment: Yes, I saw guide Jenkins restrict view of jobs per user. But, in my case, it can not be done.

Comment: please clarify where your problem is.

Comment: @S.Spieker: Yes, I installed categorized jobs plugin and create new folder view Categorized jobs as shown in the picture. 
**Step 1:** I access Manage Jenkins -> Config Global Security -> Enable security -> choose Jenkins’ own user database at Security Realm and choose Role-Based Strategy at Authorization -> Save
**Step 2: ** I create new an abc account at Manage User

Comment: ** Step 3: ** access Manage and Assign Roles -> Manage roles -> add new role and choose read at Overall. At Project roles -> add new employee with pattern Client.* -> Save. At Assign Roles -> add abc account and choice with role employee.

Comment: @S.Spieker: I just want the abc account to show Client permission and not show Admin permission.